# MySQL won't start in XAMPP Manager-osx

Tags: mysql, xampp

My XAMPP mysql server is working fine
then I download the separate mysql from oracle and installed it. It is running fine but after some days I cant start it as :> `mysql -u root`
and in xampp mysql server it is also not working it shows stopped always.
I am providing all the commands that I tried from google as well as StackOverflow
and also I am providing all results of all commands.
Please refer commands before answering.
Number indicates ways that I tried.

```
1.> `mysql -u root -p`
2.> `mysql -u root`
3.> `sudo su`
3.1.> `ps aux | grep mysql`
3.2.> `kill -9 8306`
4.> `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start`
5.> `sudo killall mysqld`
6.> Changing content of file as: `innodb_force_recovery = 1` in
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`
7.> Changing content of file as: read only permission in
`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`
8.> Port changed from 3306 to 3307 3308 but nothing is happened
9.> Activity manager : mysql service is. not listed
10.> Reinstalled XAMPP
```

I followed this 10 ways so please dont answer on this 10 ways

Result of commands :

```
<.1.
```

`Pratiks-MacBook-Pro:~ pratik$ mysql -u root -p`
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

```
<.2.
```

`Pratiks-MacBook-Pro:~ pratik$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")`

```
<.3.
```

`Pratiks-MacBook-Pro:~ pratik$ sudo su
Password:
sh-3.2# ps aux | grep mysql
root              8306   0.0  0.0  4258468    180 s000  U+   11:35AM   0:00.00 grep mysql
sh-3.2# kill -9 8306
sh: kill: (8306) - No such process
sh-3.2#`

```
<.4.
```

`Pratiks-MacBook-Pro:~ pratik$ sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
.2018-03-13 11:44:29 8513 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Pratiks-MacBook-Pro.local.err'.
2018-03-13 11:44:29 8513 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
 ERROR!`

```
<.5.
```

`Pratiks-MacBook-Pro:~ pratik$ sudo killall mysqld
No matching processes were found`